# Trouble showing only 3 thumbnails after mouse drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a thumbnail gallery, a div that show only 3 thumbnails at once, user can mouse drag left or right to show more.

current fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/31ua6jL3/2/

What i want to achieve:
-All the 6 box to align in one line, but only show the left 3 first. If outside the div, the right 3 will be hidden
-When i drag box out of the div, the box will be hidden

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image_holder">
        <div class="drag">
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="image"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have some trouble with this, and i don't want to use a plugin. Can somebody guide me on the right track?

i'm trying to do something like http://www.pikachoose.com/, u can see that it contain 5 thumbnails, what i want to do is more than 10 thumbnails in 1 line but only 5 visible, and user can mouse drag to slide to view through the other thumbnails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First what you need to do is add the following style inside .image_holder

```
overflow : hidden;
```

What ***overflow*** decides is when the contents inside a box overflows it, how should it react. Using *hidden* we've decided to make the contents hide inside the box.

***Problem in your code :***

Now as you've specified the width of .image_holder to 300px when it's inner elements will have cumulative width more then it's own width they will break down to bottom left.

***Solution :***

So to make all these elements get hidden when they overflow the .image_holder you have to keep *another div* that holds all the elements with a high range of width. Fortunately you have that div which is .drag. Just give it a bigger width,

```
.drag{
    width : 1000px;
}
```

Now this .drag div will flow inside the .image_holder and as it's width is a big value all elements will be in one row and they also will flow inside .image_holder div as you expected.

*Here's a working fiddle :*  [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/vm7vbLkm/)

**References :**

[***CSS overflow Property***](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Comment: btw, do you know how i can limit the gap the first & last element can be dragged? As for now there is no limit i can drag all the way to make all dissapear, what i want is something like if u drag to your right, the most left element cannot go off from it's parent more than 30px left, and same if i pull to the left, the last element can't go further than 30px of the right parent. Thanks